# OkHttp Request keeps running even when network fails

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 as my client and I noticed this behavior:
Whenever I start a Request and it is still running and I off my data or internet access the Request still keeps on running and doesn't stop (i.e No Callback is called)

I wrote my code like this:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

Request req = new Request.Builder()
               .url("<url>")
               .build();

client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response");
                }
            });
```

How can I stop this?

Because I want it to fail whenever the network fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could register for the `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast, so you can get notified when there is no network connection and cancel your requests.

From its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION):

> For a disconnect event, the boolean extra `EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY` is set
>   to `true` if there are no connected networks at all.

For example, in your `Activity` you could do something like this:

```
// ...

private OkHttpClient client;

private final BroadcastReceiver networkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false)) {

            // no network connection
            if (client != null && client.dispatcher() != null) {
                client.dispatcher().cancelAll();
            }
        }
    }
};

// ...

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(networkChangeReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

// ...
```